# I have run this code it will give the output 320 i want to know how this code works

Tags: c

I have run this code it will give output 320 but i want to know it works

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int main()
{
  auto int a  = 5;
   int x ; 
    x = ~a + a&a+a<<a;
    printf("%d",x);
 }
```

Comment: Try figuring it out yourself first. This might help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: **Accept one of the answers by clicking the tick on the left side below voting number**

Answer (score 3):

Using a C operator precedence table, you can break out that expression into smaller pieces with parentheses.

```
x = ~a + a&a+a<<a;
// Is equivalent to:
x = ((~a) + a) & ((a + a) << a);
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression is grouped as

```
(~a + a) & ((a + a) << a)
```

due to operator precedence. **In a 2's complement system**, `(~a + a)` is `-1` which has all bits set to 1. Hence `(~a + a) & b` is `b` for any `b`. So the expression simplifies to

```
(a + a) << a;
```

This is 10 << 5 which is 320.

Answer (score -1):

```
 x = ~a + a&a+a<<a;
 x = ((~a) + a) & ((a + a) << a);//Using a C operator precedence table
 x = (-6 + 5 ) & ( 10 << 5);
 x = (-1) & (10 * 32);
 x = (-1) & (320);
 x = 320;// bitwise AND between -1 and a number always gives that number as a result.
```

Comment: You didn't mean `2^5`.

Comment: left shifting 5 bits of number 10 will give you same result , you can try with any numbers its short trick to find the result.

Comment: But `2^5` is 7.

Comment: its actually 2 power of 5 not a xor operation

Comment: So why did you write `^`, given that this is a C question?

Comment: Thank you. Personally I'd miss out the 10 * 32 step.

Comment: i was just explaining the concept , not syntax